# Image links not working cross browser, have checked to make sure div isn't covering - what am I missing?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

All of my image links are working except for the FB and G+. This is in all browsers (IE, FF, Safari, Opera, Chrome). I have made sure I don't have any divs covering them to no avail. I know it's something ridiculous, but I'm just not seeing it... Any thoughts? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KA8nh/)

```
<div id="socialnav1">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/AmzacGarageDoors" target="_blank"><img src="images/Icons/Facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="64" height="64" /></a>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/102642746542600682870/about" target="_blank"><img src="images/Icons/Google plus.png" alt="Google+" width="64" height="64" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links are being covered by element with id `topnav`

Comment: Thank you, Carl! You're right, I thought by changing my width I had addressed that. Will post my changes for everyone to see.

Comment: Changed topnav to the following:_italic_ **bold**'#topnav {
 height: 100px;
 width: 700px;
 margin-top: 115px;
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: 435px; 
}'